# npm pack doesn't follow .npmignore

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-pack

my package tree:

```
LICENSE
README.md
main.js
package.json
- node_modules
   - m
      foo.wasm
      package.json
```

I want to `npm pack` to **include** the `node_modules/m`, the private module not be published to npmjs. Here is my `.npmignore`:

```
**/*

!main.js
!node_modules/m/package.json
!node_modules/m/foo.wasm
```

My `.gitignore`:

```
node_modules
```

But `npm pack` doesn't follow it and only pack the first four files.

```
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 35.1kB LICENSE
npm notice 104B   README.md
npm notice 12.6kB main.js
npm notice 1.2kB  package.json
```

From https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package, `npm` will use `.npmignore` first. My question is why `npm pack` does not follow it? Is there an error in my usage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In [your npmjs link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) it is said that

> Additionally, everything in node_modules is ignored, except for bundled dependencies. npm automatically handles this for you, so don't bother adding node_modules to .npmignore.

So if you add your "**m module**"
as [bundleddependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bundleddependencies) in your package.json file, npm pack will add into the pack.

But, naturally, it will also add dependencies of your "**m module**" into the pack file. Hard bounded dependencies require all hard included dependencies.